# How to create binding for FrameworkElement VisualCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, drawing

I need to draw some charts in WPF with hit testing capability. Following the instructions in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/using-drawingvisual-objects) I'm drawing the geometries as DrawingVisuals and have a host container implemented for them like this (skipping the hit testing code for brevity):

```
public class MyVisualHost : FrameworkElement
{
    public VisualCollection children;

    public MyVisualHost()
    {
        children = new VisualCollection(this);
    }
    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get { return children.Count; }
    }
    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= children.Count)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        return children[index];
    }
}
```

and use it in xaml like this

```
<local:MyVisualHost/>
```

The user can zoom and scroll the charts, and the DrawingVisuals get updated in a separate thread not to block the UI.

How do I define binding for the `children` property, so that it was possible to alter it (update DrawingVisuals contained in it) at runtime?

**Update**
I have just noticed that when you select the xaml element in the xaml editor there is VisualCollection property listed in the Properties panel.
I've tried defining binding for it, but it says:

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'VisualCollection' property of type
>   '...MyVisualHost...'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a
>   DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject

Answer (score -2):

First of all you will need some public properties on your container...

```
public class MyVisualHost : FrameworkElement
{
    public VisualCollection children;

    public MyVisualHost()
    {
        children = new VisualCollection(this);
        children.Add(new Button() {Name = "button"});
        children.Add(new TextBox() {Name = "textbox"});
    }
    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get { return children.Count; }
    }
    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= children.Count)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        return children[index];
    }

    public int Count => VisualChildrenCount;
    public Visual this[int index]
    {
        get { return GetVisualChild(index); }
    }
}
```

Next define it in XAML like this...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyVisualHost x:Key="MyVisualHost"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Finally bind to the properties like this...

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Count, Source={StaticResource MyVisualHost}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=[0].Name, Source={StaticResource MyVisualHost}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```